# Significane versus null hypothesis for small number of data

Tags: hypothesis-testing, chi-squared-test, binomial-distribution, small-sample, t-distribution

I have a model that correctly identifies something seven times out of the finite number of 8 data points as true.

I was wondering how can I calculate a significance statistics given the very low number of data points, for example as opposed to a random assigner.

I can deal with this by calculating the binomial distribution, but then I should calculate the probability of seven or more! within the 8 tries which does not make sense to me.

I can calculate the chi-square test for this but have trouble considering this as a two-sided chi-square that does not make sense to me either as there is right and wrong, and not merely head and tail.

Lastly, it seems to me that I should use the student-t somehow due to small numbers but I am not certain how to do that on the binary categorical.

Any explanation will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The small sample size means that any asymptotic results will not be appropriate. A simple alternative is to do a [permutation test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resampling_(statistics)#Permutation_tests) which would work as follows:

1. Let $(x_i, y_i)=(x_{1,i},\dots,x_{p,i}, y_i)$ be your dataset, for $i=1,2,\dots,n$. Let $T$ denote the  number of correct predictions of your model.
2. Create a permuted dataset by rearranging the $(x_i, y_i)$ combinations. In other words, for each $y_i$, randomly select (without replacement) a different $x_i$ and assign it to this $y_i$. If your model is not true, i.e., no predictive power exists between $x_i$ and $y_i$, then this randomization will have no effect on the predictability or lack thereof of your model. The result is a permuted dataset: $(x_i^{b}, y_i^b)$.
3. Repeat this $B$ times, for large $B$, to get a collection of permuted datasets.
4. For each permuted dataset $b$, refit the model, and calculate the number of correct predictions $T(b)$.
5. Compare the number of correct predictions of your original (unpermuted) dataset to the distribution of correct predictions of the permuted datasets, i.e., calculate the $p$-value $p=\frac{1}{B}\sum_{b=1}^{B} \mathbb{1}\{T(b)>T\}$ where $\mathbb{1}$ is the indicator function.
6. If $p$ is small, then the probability of getting that many predictions by pure chance is small, and so you conclude that your model has statistically significant predictive power. If $p$ is large, then it is not statistically significant.

Generally speaking permutation/randomization tests are easy to formulate but have comparatively less power than parametric tests. Since your sample size is so small, I suspect the $p$-value is unlikely to be statistically significant, so you might wish to first try a suitable parametric test before resorting to a randomization test. Nevertheless, the $p$-value can still help to inform you about how statistically significant your results are.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your descriptive answer!